# Pandas GroupBy Multiindex subset

Tags: pandas, group-by, multi-index

I have this DF which is a result of a groupby and pd.Grouper on month:

```
                                            Commitment ID
Team by product        Commitment Due Date               
A                      2016-11-30                       2
                       2017-04-30                       2
                       2018-01-31                      16
                       2019-09-30                      35
                       2020-04-30                      29
                       2020-11-30                     202
                       2020-12-31                      35
                       2021-01-31                      20
                       2021-09-30                       1
                       2021-10-31                       1
                       2022-06-30                      11
                       2022-07-31                       5
                       2022-08-31                       1
                       2022-09-30                      10
                       2022-10-31                      66
                       2022-11-30                       6
                       2022-12-31                      53
B                      2021-03-31                       1
                       2021-10-31                      11
                       2022-06-30                       1
                       2022-07-31                       3
                       2022-09-30                       1
                       2022-10-31                       1
                       2022-11-30                       2
                       2022-12-31                       1
```

I can subset it by 'Team by product' with `byteammonths.loc[['A']]`, but how can I subset it also by 'Commitment Due Date'? How can I achieve this result for example?

```
                                            Commitment ID
Team by product        Commitment Due Date               
A                      2016-11-30                       2
                       2017-04-30                       2
                       2018-01-31                      16
                       2019-09-30                      35
                       2020-04-30                      29
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query('`Team by product` == "A" & `Commitment Due Date` <= "2020-04-30"')
print (df)
                                     Commitment ID
Team by product Commitment Due Date               
A               2016-11-30                       2
                2017-04-30                       2
                2018-01-31                      16
                2019-09-30                      35
                2020-04-30                      29
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df.index.get_level_values('Commitment Due Date') <= '2020-04-30'
m2 = df.index.get_level_values('Team by product') == 'A'

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
                                     Commitment ID
Team by product Commitment Due Date               
A               2016-11-30                       2
                2017-04-30                       2
                2018-01-31                      16
                2019-09-30                      35
                2020-04-30                      29
```